# Eclipse new Web Application Project, can't find my GAE SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I've installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.4 and it seems to work fine.

But when I start a new Web Application Project, it wants me to configure the Google App Engine SDK.  I click on Add App Engine SDK, but it doesn't recognize my (valid) GAE SDK.  It comes back with "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at %path", no matter what path I give it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying to use the Java or Python SDKs, and are you sure you downloaded the right one?

If Python, remember that the Google Eclipse plugin is currently Java-only.

Answer (score 1):

Does your SDK run if you start dev_appserver from the command line?  I had a similar problem once and it was because the script wanted to ask me about automatically checking for updates - once I'd answered the question and exited the appserver I was then able to add it to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your "path" environment variable to include

;C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\

Comment: Yeah, I thought that too, but it's in my path.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I downloaded the java zip package and extracted it manually but it turned out that the zip file was either corrupted or messed up during the extraction. Regardless, downloading the package again and re-extracting it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are on Python use the PyDev plugin for eclipse and start a Google AE project that way. Use the Google Eclipse plugin for GWT, Java->Js stuff.